# Metatag OpenGraph for youtube video using Embbed Video field module

Tags: tokens, meta-tags

I cannot find a way to make Metatag Opengraph use the correct tokens for sharing video content type on Facebook.

My field is field_video and I am using it in video in opengraph. Since this is not working, can I at least make the image representing the video shared? Is it stored in Drupal? In tokens there is no thumb token for it.

I am using Drupal 7, the [Video Embed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module, and the Metatag module 7.1.4.

Comment: Add Drupal version tag in your question. Provide some information about you have done already.

Comment: D7, Metatag 1.4. Like for the image field on other content types i added token that represents Youtube video link to video field. I can not serve videos from server, so if it only works this way, i would be happy to get thumbnail image from Video Embed Field atleast. I have tried to find token for thumbnail image from Video Embed Field but there is none available.